# Why does parameter round in ffmpeg's cropdetect default to 16?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been experimenting with some ffmpeg options and I could not figure out, why the resulting files had been in a format I did not want. After further combing through the man pages, I realized that i used `cropdetect=24:16:0` in my video filters. This was a result of googling and copy-pasting. After reading the man page, I changed the values to `cropdetect=24:2:0`, which got me to the results I expected (video of 720x540, SAR 1/1, DAR 4/3).

"Sadly", the man pages states:

> round:
>   The value which the width/height should be divisible by. It defaults to 16. The offset is automatically adjusted to center the video. Use 2 to get only even dimensions (needed for 4:2:2 video). 16 is best when encoding to most video codecs.

I cannot find information, why 16 should/could be "best" for "most video codecs". Can you give me a hint? Do I do anything severely wrong, if I use '2' instead of '16'?

Comment: I found http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/optimal-video-dimensions which states again, that everything should at best be a multiple of 16, or, if needed of 8 or 4. Again no explanation, no reasoning, just the statement.

Comment: It seems like this might be due to video compression itself: http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-143215.html holds a comment by LoRd_MuldeR, who states that the compression (still generalized) works on blocks ofh the size 16x16 and that smaller parts of the pictures will be padded. But he also states: "However with x264 the cost for none-mod16 is pretty low. Wouldn't worry too much!" This is enough of an explanation for me, so perhaps anyone else might stumble over this. Have fun.